# Pyarrow : Decimal not fitting with precision inferred

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I'm currently trying to construct a parquet file using pyarrow.
For that purpose I'm using that piece of code:

```py
def create_dataframe(list_dict: dict) -> pa.table:
    fields = set()
    for d in list_dict:
        fields = fields.union(d.keys())
    dataframe = pa.table({f: [row.get(f) for row in list_dict] for f in fields})
    return dataframe
```

Everything works well for most of the cases. But I have an issue with one particular case where I have the following error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Decimal type with precision 7 does not fit into precision inferred from first array element: 8
```

This problem occurs with a nested value as in the following example bellow the `lines` where the amount and sold price can be a integer or :

```json
[{"accounted_at": "2022-01-31T22:55:25.702000+00:00", "booked_at": "2022-01-27T09:24:17.539000+00:00", "booked_by": "7b3ce009-728d-4fbc-9120-00fa8c1c8655", "created_at": "2022-01-27T09:08:22.306000+00:00", "created_by": "7b3ce009-728d-4fbc-9120-00fa8c1c8655", "deleted_at": null, "description": "description of the record", "due_date": "2022-02-10T00:00:00+00:00", "franchise_id": "9a2858c4-5c71-43d3-b28f-2352de47ff9f", "id": "ba3f6d3a-12f4-4d78-acc5-2e59ca384c1e", "internal_code": "A.2022 / 9", "invoice_recipient_id": "7169cef9-9cb2-461f-a38f-a4d1ce3ca1c3", "lines": [{"type": "property", "amount": 7800, "soldPrice": 260000, "commission": 3, "description": "Honoraires de l'agence", "commissionUnit": "PERCENT"}], "parent_id": null, "payment_term": "14-days", "recipient_emails": null, "sent_at": null, "sent_by": null, "status": "booked", "teamleader_id": "xxx-yyy-www-zzz", "type": "out"}, {"accounted_at": null, "booked_at": "2022-01-05T09:23:03.274000+00:00", "booked_by": "8a91a22d-ddb9-491a-bc2d-c06ff3f256b4", "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:21:32.503000+00:00", "created_by": "8a91a22d-ddb9-491a-bc2d-c06ff3f256b4", "deleted_at": null, "description": "Description content", "due_date": "2022-02-04T00:00:00+00:00", "franchise_id": "929d47a3-c30f-404b-aaff-c96cff1bdd10", "id": "828cd056-6aa7-4cea-9c94-ffa2db4498df", "internal_code": "BXC22 / 3", "invoice_recipient_id": "5f90aa24-4c32-401d-927c-db9d4a9f90bf", "lines": [{"type": "property", "amount": 92.55, "soldPrice": 3702.02, "commission": 2.5, "description": "description2", "commissionUnit": "PERCENT"}], "parent_id": null, "payment_term": "30-days", "recipient_emails": null, "sent_at": "2022-01-05T09:27:34.077000+00:00", "sent_by": "8a91a22d-ddb9-491a-bc2d-c06ff3f256b4", "status": "credited", "teamleader_id": "xxx-yzyzy-zzz-www", "type": "out"}]
```

Do you have any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? The list of dicts you provided is processed fine by the function for me. And did you specify a decimal type? Because by default those numeric columns will be converted to a float64 (double) type.

Comment: Thank you joris for your prompt answer. Weirdly enough, the issue was coming from pyarrow's version. I was using 6.0.1. Using the 4.0.1 is safe. My only issue now is realted to `FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY` now

Comment: If something is working in 4.0.1, but not anymore in 6.0.1, that sounds as a regression, and it would be good to report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW/issues

Comment: I'll definitely raise the point. Thank you for your time!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-15547 For further reference.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this would be to specify a schema with the desired precision and scale for the Decimal column that can accommodate all the values you are passing through (you could also make these value float if that was desired, but I'd guess not since they seem to be dollar values).

This will prevent any issues with Arrow trying to infer the scale and precision which as you've seen can be error prone.

The error message is somewhat out of data (thank you for filing the JIRA).

Comment: This is indeed the way we could conduct a solution for this issue. However, the schemas are automatically generated on the fly for each of the tables I'm ingesting ( and we are talking about hundreds !) So it will not be easily maintainable in the end. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import Decimal

your_precision = ".2f" # example

df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: format(float(x), your_precision)).apply(Decimal)
```